# VBA - Split table rows based on a column value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with two columns, columnA and columnB.
columnA has several types and for eachtype, there are values in columnB.
I would like to create a sheet for each type containing the corresponding rows.

I tried looping through each type, create a sheet, and paste the found rows but I have a lot of data and it proves to be quite time consuming.

Does anyone have a better idea?

I tried looping through each type, create a sheet, and paste the found rows but I have a lot of data and it proves to be quite time consuming.

Comment: If you do it right, this shouldn't take too much time, even if you have a large sheet. Start by showing your code, maybe it is something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

### Create Type-Specific Worksheets in Excel using VBA

[image]

**Description**

- This is a VBA code for creating type-specific worksheets in Excel based on a unique column value in a source worksheet.

**The Code**

```vb
Sub CreateTypeWorksheets()

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const UNIQUE_COLUMN As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the source data to an array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Populate a dictionary with the unique types
    ' and their corresponding row numbers.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sr As Long, sStr As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sStr = CStr(sData(sr, UNIQUE_COLUMN))
        If Not dict.Exists(sStr) Then Set dict(sStr) = New Collection
        dict(sStr).Add sr
    Next sr
    
    ' Create the template worksheet.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    sws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

    With tws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Resize(srCount).Offset(1).Clear
    End With
    
    ' Create the type-specific worksheets.
        
    Dim dsh As Object, dData(), Key, rItem, dr As Long, c As Long
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        ' Write to an array.
        ReDim dData(1 To dict(Key).Count, 1 To cCount)
        For Each rItem In dict(Key)
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(dr, c) = sData(rItem, c)
            Next c
        Next rItem
        ' Delete existing worksheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dsh = wb.Sheets(Key)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
                dsh.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Set dsh = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
        ' Create the worksheet.
        tws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        ' Copy data from the array.
        With wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
            .Name = Key
            .Range("A2").Resize(dr, cCount).Value = dData
        End With
        dr = 0 ' reset for the next iteration
    Next Key
    
    ' Delete the template worksheet.
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
        tws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Inform.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Type worksheets created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**The Flow**

- The code first defines constants for the source worksheet name and the column that contains the unique values. It then sets up variables for the workbook, source worksheet, source data range, and a dictionary object for grouping data by unique values.
- The code then loops through the source data, adds each unique value to the dictionary, and adds the corresponding row numbers to a collection within the dictionary.
- The code then creates a new worksheet as a template for the type-specific worksheets and clears any existing data. It then loops through the dictionary, creating a new worksheet for each unique value and copying the rows from the source data that correspond to that value.
- If a worksheet with the same name already exists, the code deletes it first to avoid conflicts. Once all the type-specific worksheets have been created, the template worksheet is deleted.
- Finally, the code displays a message box to inform the user that the process is complete.

Comment: Hi VBasic2008, thanks for taking the time. I appreciate it. I am trying your code out, I have a problem at the following line Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value which basically says overflow. In my example, there are two columns but in my workbook there are 60 columns and tens of thousands of rows. I am guessing this is the problem. 
Is there any object which can store that many values?

Comment: There shouldn't be an overflow. What does `Debug.Print srg.Address` return (put it above the line)? Also, could you try with e.g. half of the data i.e. determine how many rows can be covered without an overflow?